# Inserting a Document As a Field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Let' say I have a company collection:

```
[{
    name: 'x',
    code: 'a',
},
{
    name: 'y',
    code: 'b',
}]
```

I want to find the company with code 'a' and insert this to another collection called projects. I wrote something like this:

```
 var collectionP = db.collection('projects');
 var collectionC = db.collection('company');
 var foundCompany = collectionC.find({code: 'a'});
 db.collectionP.insert(name: 'project1', company: foundCompany);
```

This doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `find` returns a [cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/cursors/#cursors), not a result set.

Your alternatives are either iterate over the cursor, if expecting multiple results:

```
var foundCompany = collectionC.find({code: 'a'});
foundCompany.forEach(function(fc) { 
 db.collectionP.insert(name: 'project1', company: fc);
}
```

or convert it into an array if you want all results in one document:

```
var foundCompany = collectionC.find({code: 'a'}).toArray();
db.collectionP.insert(name: 'project1', company: foundCompany);
```

or if you only expect to match a single company, use findOne or its equivalent in your language:

```
var foundCompany = collectionC.findOne({code: 'a'});
db.collectionP.insert(name: 'project1', company: foundCompany);
```